# Sharpest camera shoot within a mirror

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reflection

In order to take the sharpest camera shoot from the reflected object image in the mirror, the camera should be placed $x\,m$ farther from the reflected image object.

[image]

How can I determine $x$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't without knowing the focal length of the camera.  Remember that all a flat mirror does is "fold" the distances in the system.  Unfold the optical path and adjust as appropriate for the camera's focal length.